# Get opposite element of 2-tuple

Tags: python, tuples, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

Currently have a piece of code that looks like this

```py
node = {"id": 1, "some-other-data": "foo"}
edges = [(1, 0), (2, 1)]
adjacent = []
for edg in edges:
    if node["id"] == edg[0]:
        adjacent.append(edg[1])
    elif node["id"] == edg[1]:
        adjacent.append(edg[0])
```

I was wondering if there was a more 'pythonic' way of checking to see if the ID
was an element of a tuple in the adjacency list and assigning the opposite
element. In essence this is the adjacency matrix of an undirected graph.

Comment: use iterable unpacking, `for x, y in edges: ...`

Comment: I don't really see how that makes it more pythonic or more concise...

Comment: I think this would fit better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I posted it here because I thought it was general enough of a question to
generate an answer outside of the scope of just this code (see title)

Comment: @zr0gravity7 Iterable unpacking is preferred over indexing into a tuple like that. It is the lowest hanging fruit here.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's automatically preferred. It being a feature of the language does not necessarily make its usage more pythonic. In this case, I don't see the use in giving arbitrary variable names that will be used twice. Simply accessing the 1st and 2nd endpoint of an edge seems clearer than logic involving some `x` and `y` variables.

Comment: @ThomasCarroll What is "pythonic" is a matter of opinion, which makes this a general code review and off-topic. If you are concerned about something *objective*, like compliance with PEP-8, or at least without using some *specific* implementation method (like, without loops for example), you can rephrase the question to be about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html?highlight=index#array.array.index) method:

```
node = {"id": 1, "some-other-data": "foo"}
edges = [(1, 0), (2, 1)]
adjacent = []
for edg in edges:
    try:
        i = edg.index(node["id"])
        adjacent.append(edg[~i])
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Here we follow the pythonic approach of [asking for forgiveness](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-eafp), and use bitwise negation (`~`) to turn an index of 0 and 1 into 1 and 0, respectively.

It has the same exact runtime, as the size of the edges lists is constant, so it is still O(|E|).

You could also replace the `try/except` blocks with a simple `if` statement to check if the node's id is in the set of endpoints of the current edge.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly collapse the code. This line does the same thing as your entire `for` + `if` block. However, whether or not this is the most Pythonic is dubious since readability counts and this is pretty compacted.

```py
adjacent = [x[int(node['id'] == x[0])] for x in edges if node['id'] in x]
```

A compromise might look like this. It retains some of the shortcuts, but lays it out over a bit more space to keep things readable.

```py
for edge in edges:
    if node['id'] in edge:
        index = int(node['id'] == x[0])
        adjacent.append(edge[index])
```

Both of these code blocks function off testing whether the first element in a tuple matches the node id and converting that boolean value to an integer.

Comment: note, converting from `bool`  to`int` is not strictly necessary, although it may be clarfiying, because `issubclass(bool, int)` is true (although, I think ultimately here `bool.__index__` is called)